# Spinner Not Clickable Only on Samsung Galaxy Note 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, samsung-mobile

In one activity, I have a `Spinner` linked to a `ViewPager`. I use `ButterKnife` to listen for the item selected with the `@OnItemSelected` annotation. And I use a custom layout and adapter to create the `Spinner`:

```
public class BaseFragmentSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseFragment>
        implements ThemedSpinnerAdapter {

    private final ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper mDropDownHelper;

    public BaseFragmentSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<BaseFragment> fragments) {
        this(context, fragments.toArray(new BaseFragment[fragments.size()]));
    }

    public BaseFragmentSpinnerAdapter(Context context, BaseFragment... fragments) {
        super(context, R.layout.view_spinner_item, fragments);
        mDropDownHelper = new ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_spinner_title, parent, false);
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(getItem(position).getTitle(getContext()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_spinner_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText(getItem(position).getTitle(getContext());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Resources.Theme getDropDownViewTheme() {
        return mDropDownHelper.getDropDownViewTheme();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDropDownViewTheme(Resources.Theme theme) {
        mDropDownHelper.setDropDownViewTheme(theme);
    }

}
```

The spinner item layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_standard" android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_accent" android:textSize="@dimen/font_subhead"/>
```

Lastly, the selector for the text color of the spinner item layout:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    <item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

This code works great on both of my test devices (Nexus 5X and Nexus 7, both on 6.0.1), and all of the emulators I tried (AVD Manager and Genymotion) ranging from versions 4.1 to 6.0. The layout looks like this:

[image: Android Spinner Working]

But one of my users reported an issue on a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running 5.1.1. The unselected item text is appearing white, and the items are not clickable:

[image: Android Spinner Broken]

Has anyone run into similar issues with a Galaxy Note 4 (or another device)? Any ideas on what could be causing this?